# SQL Query to get manager name for employee with 2 tables (many to many)

Tags: sql, dapper

I'm trying to learn using Dapper instead of EF Core because I want to learn the basics of SQL first.
So far I have learned at a steady pace but now I'm stuck with the following.

I have 2 Tables, `Employees` and `Managers`.
One employee can have more than 1 manager in our firm. So that is the reason why I have to use 2 tables for the many to many relations and since a manager is also an employee, I only need two tables.

So in the `Managers` table, we have 2 foreign keys:
`ManagerId` (references back to the `Employees` table)
`EmployeeId` (references back to the `Employees` table)
Obviously, the name of the manager is not in that table, since we should be able to get it from the `Employees` table.

I can write the query to get the users and their manager id with an inner join, that works.

```
SELECT emp.EmailAddress, man.ManagerId 
FROM Employees emp 
LEFT JOIN Managers man ON emp.EmployeeId = man.EmployeeId
```

So far so good, but... what I actually want to see is the Managers name. Most examples I see online are mostly with a 1 emp has 1 manager query style, but now when you have a many to many like in my case.

So what is the best solution that I can actually yet again go back to `Employees` table to get the Managers name?

I hope my question is clear enough, thank you for the help!

Comment: Hint: You can reference the same table twice with different aliases

Comment: Indeed, I feel so silly now, but I feel that such examples are not asked that often, a lot of firms do like, 1 emp has 1 manager and that's it. :) But thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the manager's details you need to join again on Employees. Something like this:

```
SELECT emp.EmailAddress, man.ManagerId, manDetails.Name
FROM Employees emp 
LEFT JOIN Managers man ON emp.EmployeeId = man.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN Employees manDetails ON man.ManagerId = manDetails.EmployeeId
```